# Is there a way to let me switch delay before/after distortion without needing additional pedals?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

I use a modelling setup for my amp and effects I don't have/want dedicated pedals for, with a proper delay pedal (TC Electronic Flashback). I typically have the setup:

Guitar->Tuner->Delay->Modeller->DI->PA

But sometimes delay leads to really muddy sounds when I use distortion or a noisy amp. I could put the delay after the modeller :

Guitar->Tuner->Modeller->Delay->DI->PA

But ideally I'd like to be able to switch this on the fly. Is there a way to do this without just buying a 2nd delay pedal - I dislike having a lot of kit and I'm on a budget. Is there a common way to do this using clever cable/switch setup?

Comment: It depends partly on the modeller and how the delay pedal is connected - on my Line6 X3L, there is an effects loop that can be switched pre- or post-amp.

Comment: Sadly not for me - I'm using Amplitube on my iPad so I just have signal in, signal out and the modeller combines amp modelling with any effects I don't have real pedals for.

Comment: If Amplitube has a delay pedal, you could use that as your post-amp delay.

Comment: Their pedals all go pre-amp (I think the desktop version is different) but regardless their delay is very basic. It is an option, just not the ideal one.

Comment: I use the AmpKit app, which lets you place effects between amp and cabinet. Amplitube may have the same feature hidden in the interface somewhere. Check the interface for editing pedal order – it may be in there.

Answer (score 3):

Conventional wisdom is to put timing effects like delay and reverb absolutely last in your effects chain. If you use an effects loop, they would usually go in the loop *after* the pre-amp stage and all other effects, so it makes sense to put your delay pedal after the modeler. Most guitarists do it that way to avoid exactly the kind of muddiness you are experiencing. So unless you have a specific need to modify your delay effect, I recommend simply moving it after your modeler.

Comment: Oh... I'm _sure_ I read that conventionally you'd do something like compressor->delay->distortion->reverb. Possibly I just mis-read. Thanks, I'll check around the web :)

Comment: The usual chain is envelope, gain, modulation, timing. Compression and distortion are part of the gain phase.

Comment: Cheers. In my case my distortion and amp are in the same unit so I have to put by delay before or after the entire modeller. I'll also have to figure out if the output signal (using Amplitube iOS) is safe for my Flashback pedal.

Comment: GMT -- Gain Modulation Time -- is how I learned it. And as delays often chime l come between the preamp and power amp sections of amps, your Flashback should handle your iPad.

Comment: The preamp is usually considered part of the gain stage, which is why you put mod and time pedals between the preamp and power amp (and why amps have effects loops).

Comment: Ah, I guess it makes sense to think of the iPad as the pre-amp in this scenario then - the output goes through DI->PA so what comes out of the iPad should be safe.